# What is "contents: write" permission in GitHub workflow?

Tags: github, github-actions

Recently I've faced an issue https://github.com/kkohtaka/gh-actions-pr-size/issues/9 that has a possible [solution](https://github.com/actions/first-interaction/issues/10#issuecomment-1041402989) as adding `contents: write` permission to my job:

```yaml
permissions:
   contents: write
   ...
```

I've tried to find an explanation for it in https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs but found only supported values like `contents: read|write|none`.

What is `contents: write` permission in GitHub workflow? What does it give?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The token permissions are based on the GitHub App permission model.

You can refer to the [overview for the GitHub App `contents` permission](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/permissions-required-for-github-apps?apiVersion=2022-11-28#repository-permissions-for-contents).

Comment: That link is not (at least not any longer particularly readable.